# CRM Javascript to Check Entity Type

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm using CRM 2013, I'm writing a JavaScript to check if there is any 'Queue' type entity in the email participants list.

I'm stuck on the part, where I have to write the script to check for this Queue data type.

The MSDN article suggested to use `Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName()`, however I'm not sure if it works if I plug-in the entity name in there like:

```
toParty[indxAttendees].getEntityName()
```

Appreciate your help.

```
function deleteSenderQueueFromEmail() {
  var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();

  if (formType == 1 || formType == 2) {

    var toParty = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue();
    var ccParty = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cc").getValue();
    var bcParty = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("bcc").getValue();


    for (var indxAttendees = 0; indxAttendees < toParty.length; indxAttendees++) {

      if (toParty[indxAttendees].getEntityName() == "queue") {
        //delete the queue from the list of participants
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it record when you log "toParty[indxAttendees].getEntityName()" into the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName()` gets the logical name of the entity that is displayed on the form. On an e-mail form this will always be "email".

The lookup values you are looking for are in arrays that are part of the To/Cc/Bcc fields. A lookup value is an object with `id`, `entityType` and `name` property.

I would suggest a function accepting a party list parameter.

```
function deleteSenderQueue(partyList) {
    if (partyList == null) {
        return;
    }

    partyList.forEach(function(party) {
        if (party.entityType === "queue") {
            // Delete the queue from the list of participants.
        }
    });
}
```

This function can be used like this:

```
deleteSenderQueue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue());
```